# How to display the content of a blog post using a custom post template?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am using my own custom WordPress theme and I am running into trouble displaying the content of blog posts. I can display the title and the date it was published using php but I can't get any of the paragraphs, images, headings, etc. to display on the page. I am using Gutenberg blocks (default) for the content of the blog posts.

I have tried using php functions to grab the content but they don't seem to be working.

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

        <p class="date"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"> 
         </span> <?php echo get_the_date();?></p><br />

        <p><?php $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post- 
          >post_content);?></p>

</div>
```

I am expecting the content of the post to display within the div container but the function is not grabbing the content. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you run `<?php echo $content; ?>` after declaring your variable?

Comment: this worked. thanks a lot

Comment: You can also try `<?php the_content(); ?>` or `<?php echo get_the_content(); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be trying to retrieve the post content from outside the loop.

If you look at the post template for a theme e.g. [2017](https://github.com/WordPress/twentyseventeen/blob/master/single.php), it is this bit that does the magic. It’s not even necessary to pass a post ID:

```
    <?php
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            get_template_part( 'components/page/content', 'page' );
            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
            if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                comments_template();
            endif;
        endwhile; // End of the loop.
    ?>
```

E.g. you should just be able to do:

```
<?php
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            the_content();
        endwhile; // End of the loop.
?>
```

Might be a good idea to start with the code on the link above, or copy the single.php file for the theme you’re using and use that as the basis for your custom post page?